# Only an exact match number in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

How to match (without capturing): 5678

In this string: `performer=5678,25678,56342,56782`

This is what I have so far: `5678(?!\d)`

http://rubular.com/r/WqdK6sQjOK

Comment: Is the comma relevant? What's wrong about your regex?

Comment: The regex that I started matched the case 25678, I could not figure out a way to not match the first #.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\b5678\b
```

... which works also if you delimit your numbers with other separators, such as `;`, `/`, etc